# How to get turtlebot to move in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, rviz, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, keyboard-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am brand new to ROS and have had issues setting up my turtlebot_gazebo to just have the simulated turtlebot move around.

I am just trying to follow this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_gazebo/Tutorials/indigo/Make%20a%20map%20and%20navigate%20with%20it

But get stuck on Step 2, which is really just getting this http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/hydro/Explore%20the%20Gazebo%20world to work.

I run

```
roscore
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_robot.launch
```

Which both work fine.

Then I do

```
roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch
```

However, while my key presses to move the robot appear in the keyboard_teleop.launch terminal window, the robot doesn't move in Rviz.

How do I get my robot to listen to the turtlebot_telop_keyboard/cmd_vel topic if my robot only exists in simulation? Which node is the actual turtlebot?

Do I need to have

```
roslaunch turtlebot_stage turtlebot_in_stage.launch
```

be running? Because that gives me an error (Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/amcl.launch.xml').

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315020/how-to-get-turtlebot-to-move-in-gazebo?/) by [ahumay](https://answers.ros.org/users/39906/ahumay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mali](https://answers.ros.org/users/36867/mali/) on 2019-02-08**:
Hi, To figure out why the robot does not move, make sure that you are publishing on the correct topic.
so start with rostopic list and check if `keyboard_teleop` publishes on the correct topic. could you tell  which version of ros you are using indigo or kinetic?

**Comment by [ahumay](https://answers.ros.org/users/39906/ahumay/) on 2019-02-11**:
Thank you for your prompt response! When I run

```
rosnode info /turtlebot_teleop_keyboard
```

I get
Node [/turtlebot_teleop_keyboard]
Publications:

- /cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop [geometry_msgs/Twist]
- /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

So it looks right

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 and my ROS is Kinetic.

**Comment by [ahumay](https://answers.ros.org/users/39906/ahumay/) on 2019-02-11**:
Delb's solution actually has it moving now. Thank you anyways though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seems to be a bug in the script responsible to set the speed of the robot because you do have the topic `/mobile_base/commands/velocity`publishing data (this is the topic that moves the robot) but this data is always only `0` eventhough you press some keys and the script prints different speeds. So you can either investigate the script `turtlebot_teleop_key` or instead you can use another launch file that is working fine that use the mobile_base of the turtlebot directly (i.e. `kobuki`).

Try:

```
roslaunch kobuki_keyop keyop.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahumay](https://answers.ros.org/users/39906/ahumay/) on 2019-02-11**:
That worked! Thank you so much.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-02-12**:
Glad it worked, have you modified the script or just used the `kobuki_keyop` package ?

**Comment by [ahumay](https://answers.ros.org/users/39906/ahumay/) on 2019-02-12**:
Just the kobuki_keyop package, which is odd because I swore I tried it before. Obviously not though